# calculate tableviewcell height based on data from server

Tags: ios, uitableview

i want to calculate the table view cell height based on the data that return from server. due to data return late from server is late my table view cell height no able to display. is that anyway to wait until the data is return only refresh the table view cell height

Comment: Are you loading images into table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After loading data from server reload your table and for dynamic cell height features of iOS 8 to resize the cell: http://www.raywenderlich.com/73602/dynamic-table-view-cell-height-auto-layout

Comment: i'm not using autolayout.

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to wait:

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {


    if(self.data) {

        //or whatever you want here
        return 1;

    }

    else {
       return 0;


    }


    return 0;
}
```

Just zero the section if there is no data, when the data arrives reload the table view.

Comment: self.data is it the function to call load the data from server? can i have more details on that? tq

Comment: no, I'm just giving you an example. Say you have a function that loads data from the server in viewDidLoad, when it is loaded you can set a BOOL self.data = YES and then reload the table. It will then know you have data and add sections.